# How to use an analytical function to get highest and lowest price for each car make Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose you have a car table with carsaleprice, carmodel, and carmake. How do I use a analytical function to find the highest and lowest carsaleprice for each carmake and rank them by highest price in descending order?

DDL and DML

```
CREATE TABLE cars (
 carmake VARCHAR2(10),
 carmodel VARCHAR2(10),
 carsaleprice NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO cars (carmake, carmodel, carsaleprice) values ('ACURA', 'RX', 50000);
INSERT INTO cars (carmake, carmodel, carsaleprice) values ('ACURA', 'RT', 40000);

INSERT INTO cars (carmake, carmodel, carsaleprice) values ('JAGUAR', 'LT', 40000);
INSERT INTO cars (carmake, carmodel, carsaleprice) values ('JAGUAR', 'LY', 30000);

INSERT INTO cars (carmake, carmodel, carsaleprice) values ('HONDA', 'OP', 20000);
INSERT INTO cars (carmake, carmodel, carsaleprice) values ('HONDA', 'PO', 10000);

INSERT INTO cars (carmake, carmodel, carsaleprice) values ('TOYOTA', 'BN', 30000);
INSERT INTO cars (carmake, carmodel, carsaleprice) values ('TOYOTA', 'NG', 20000);
```

Desired results

```
Carmake | HighestPrice | LowestPrice | Rank
--------------------------------------------
HONDA   | 20 000       | 10 000      |  4 
--------------------------------------------
TOYOTA  | 30 000       | 20 000      |  3 
--------------------------------------------
JAGUAR  | 40 000       | 30 000      |  2 
--------------------------------------------
ACURA   | 50 000       | 40 000      |  1 
--------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: This post shows no research or effort on your part.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I added a table which is the desired result

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`. `MIN()`.  `MAX()`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff gotta use a analytical function RANK(), I don't know how

Comment: You've given desired results; please give the DDL statement for the table and DML statements for the example data that is an input to your query. Having this is just as important as having the output.

Comment: @MT0 I added the DDL and DML statements

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP BY` the `carmake` and then the `MAX`imum price will be the highest price, the `MIN`imum price will be the lowest price and you can use the `RANK` analytic function ordered by the `MAX`imum price in `DESC`ending order:

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT carmake,
       MAX( carsaleprice ) AS HighestPrice,
       MIN( carsaleprice ) AS LowestPrice,
       RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY MAX( carsaleprice ) DESC ) AS "RANK"
FROM   cars
GROUP BY carmake
ORDER BY HighestPrice
```

**Output**:

> ```
> CARMAKE | HIGHESTPRICE | LOWESTPRICE | RANK
> :------ | -----------: | ----------: | ---:
> HONDA   |        20000 |       10000 |    4
> TOYOTA  |        30000 |       20000 |    3
> JAGUAR  |        40000 |       30000 |    2
> ACURA   |        50000 |       40000 |    1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=685c4a696d20032d40207770b5127482)*